# Can we use Data Driven approach with Page Object model using Page Factory, any example or link will help

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, page-objects, data-driven

Can we use Data Driven approach with Page Object model using Page Factory, any example or link will help. I am trying to implement POM with PageFactory but at the same time I want to make it data driven using excel file
Following is the code snippet after data driven and after data driven is not working

```
@Test
public void valid_email_password()
{
    int iNoofRows = objexcel.rowCount();
    for(int i=1; i<iNoofRows; i++)
    {
    objLogin = new ScoreLogin(driver);
    objLogin.loginScore(objexcel.getData(0, i, 0), objexcel.getData(0, i, 1));
    objHomePage = new HomePage(driver);
    String DashboardUserName = objHomePage.getHomePageUserName();
    Assert.assertTrue(DashboardUserName.contains("Super Admin"));
    }
}
```

Following is the code snippet before data driven

```
@Test
public void valid_email_password()
{
    int iNoofRows = objexcel.rowCount();
    for(int i=1; i<iNoofRows; i++)
    {
    objLogin = new ScoreLogin(driver);
    objLogin.loginScore("testuser", "testpassword");
    objHomePage = new HomePage(driver);
    String DashboardUserName = objHomePage.getHomePageUserName();
    Assert.assertTrue(DashboardUserName.contains("Super Admin"));
    }
}
```

Comment: That are two orthogonal problems. What problem are you having with combining both?

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: You have my permission to use data driven approach. Rest is "matter of simple programming". Sorry no examples, I try to avoid Java, and in Python I did not ever felt the need for factory pattern yet.

Comment: What you're wanting is called a Parameterized Test in JUnit.  https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Parameterized-tests

Comment: The overhead of the page factory will be minimal compared to the network latency and page waits.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, we have 2 parts as follow: Let me use **C# Selenium**.

1. Organizing the Definition of test objects using **page factory**.
   [**Please have a look in my answer at another thread**](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/28482/balancing-readability-and-reliability-in-end-to-end-testing/28495#28495)
2. Data Driven approach for you test functions, and to handle this part we have to handle 2 points.

   1. Data management functions to handle use SQL queries to read/update Excel sheets.

**Excel Connection String, to be stored in config file**

```
<add name="MyExcelConn" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=[Path to Test Data Sheet];Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES';"/>
```

**Sample Reading , function to return data table.**

```
public static DataTable GetExcelDataTable(string query)
        {

            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
            if (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyExcelConn"] != null)
                conn.ConnectionString =ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyExcelConn"].ConnectionString;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            OleDbCommand cmd;
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection));

                return dt;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

               // log error
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

2. How to Drive the Test Data for you test functions.

**Design of Excel Sheet**

[image: Excel sheet sample login test data]

**Test Function Design, After following the previous shared answer above. your function will looks like this**

```
public static bool Login(DataRow loginTable)
        {
            bool retRes = true;
            try
            {
                Browser.pgLogin.txtUserName.SetValue(loginTable["userID"].ToString().Trim());                
                Browser.pgLogin.txtPassword.SetValue(loginTable["Password"].ToString().Trim());                
                Browser.pgLogin.btnSignin.Click();

                return retRes;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               // Log error
                return false;
            }
        }
```

**Data Table to hold Test Data**

```
 DataRow loginRow = null;
loginRow = GetExcelDataTable("Select * from [Login$] where RowID = " + iLoginRow).Rows[0];
```

**Calling the Test Function with Test Data**

```
Login(loginRow );
```

**I hope this helps you and answers your question. for more details we can chat.**

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution could be-
You can use dataprovider annotation of testNG for the same. in dataprovider method write logic for reading excel file and in test cases use that dataprovider method.

Comment: Considering how old this question is, could you please edit your answer to show some example code? That would make this a better answer to a question that could benefit from the attention.